# Combine List records in C#

Tags: c#, list, data-structures

I have the following List

```
List<List<RecordItem>> combinedList = new List<List<RecordItem>>();

public class RecordItem
    {
        public string fieldName { get; set; }
        public string value { get; set; }
    }
```

The sample of the this data structure:

```
[0] [0]fieldName = "StudentId", value = "S1"
    [1]fieldName = "Maths", value = "90"

[1] [0]fieldName = "StudentId", value = "S1"
    [1]fieldName = "Science", value = "70"

[2] [0]fieldName = "StudentId", value = "S2"
    [1]fieldName = "Maths", value = "60"

[3] [0]fieldName = "StudentId", value = "S2"
    [1]fieldName = "Science", value = "50"
```

I need to combine these rows to get the following output,
I am not sure how to use LINQ with LAMBDA her to do a group by as this is a two dimensional object list.

```
var groupedList = combinedList.GroupBy(u => u.???).Select(grp => grp.ToList()).ToList();

[0] [0]fieldName = "StudentId", value = "S1"
    [1]fieldName = "Maths", value = "90"
    [2]fieldName = "Science", value = "70"

[1] [0]fieldName = "StudentId", value = "S2"
    [1]fieldName = "Maths", value = "60"
    [2]fieldName = "Science", value = "50"
```

Thanks,

Comment: are you sure? input have 2 Maths and 2 Science, output have 3 Science and 1 Maths

Comment: "What I need ... thanks" isn't really the way to ask a question here. Show what you have tried.

Comment: Use  `Group By`. Try this and in case of issue come here.

Comment: Can you please give me an example. Thx

Comment: Show the code that isnt't working.

Comment: var groupedList = combinedList.GroupBy(u => u.???).Select(grp => grp.ToList()).ToList();

Comment: It would be really great if the data you present could be compilable c#. That would make it so much easier for us to answer.

Comment: It looks to me that your `RecordItem` class is used to hold two different types of data which you then bundle all together with no obvious way of distinguishing the two different types.   The first thing I would do is define a `StudentRecordItem` class and a `CourseRecordItem` (or `CourseResultRecordItem`) class to replace the abiguous `RecordItem`.  You can always inherit from `RecordItem` if need be.

Comment: Are you after `combinedList.GroupBy(u => u[0].value)`? Your question still seems a little unclear to me and you may benefit by rethinking your structure into a richer object

Comment: @DafaDil the structure you are having needs to be improved anyways I created fiddle working for you : https://dotnetfiddle.net/jNrSWo

Comment: temp variable will have what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you should have presented your data in your question:

```
List<List<RecordItem>> combinedList = new List<List<RecordItem>>()
{
    new List<RecordItem>()
    {
        new RecordItem() { fieldName = "StudentId", value = "S1" },
        new RecordItem() { fieldName = "Maths", value = "90" },
    },
    new List<RecordItem>()
    {
        new RecordItem() { fieldName = "StudentId", value = "S1" },
        new RecordItem() { fieldName = "Science", value = "70" },
    },
    new List<RecordItem>()
    {
        new RecordItem() { fieldName = "StudentId", value = "S2" },
        new RecordItem() { fieldName = "Maths", value = "60" },
    },
    new List<RecordItem>()
    {
        new RecordItem() { fieldName = "StudentId", value = "S2" },
        new RecordItem() { fieldName = "Science", value = "50" },
    },
};
```

Now with that I can do this:

```
List<List<RecordItem>> groupedList =
(
    from records in combinedList
    from student in records.Take(1)
    let StudentId = student.value
    let Subjects = records.Skip(1)
    group Subjects by StudentId into gss
    select new []
    {
        new RecordItem() { fieldName = "StudentId", value = gss.Key },
    }.Concat(gss.SelectMany(x => x)).ToList()
).ToList();
```

I get this result:

[image: result]

This code assumes that the `StudentId` record is always first. If it's not then it wouldn't take too much to add a couple of `.Where` clauses to replace the `.Take(1)` & `.Skip(1)` operators.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad - LOL - The only reason it is hacky is because the original data structure is.

Comment: Hi Enigmativity, Thanks a lot for the help, just one more question, if I wanted to add another field into the group by how can I include it in  new RecordItem() { fieldName = "StudentId", value = gss.Key },

Comment: select new[]
                                    {
                                        new RecordItem() { fieldName = "StudentId", value = gss.Key },
                                        new RecordItem() {fieldName = "Term", value = gss.Key },
                                    }

Comment: @DafaDil - You want to group by both `StudentId` and `Term` - is that right?

Comment: Yes StudentId and Term

Comment: got it resolved, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28989944/group-by-multiple-fields-c-sharp-with-object-list

Answer (score 1):

```
        List<List<RecordItem>> result = combinedList
            .Select(l =>
                combinedList
                    .Where(ls =>
                        ls.Exists(r1 => r1.fieldName == "StudentId" && r1.value == l.First(r2 => r2.fieldName == "StudentId").value)
                    ).SelectMany(lz => lz.Select(lx=>lx)).GroupBy(r=>new { id = r.fieldName, v = r.value }).Select(r=>r.First()).ToList()
            )
            .GroupBy(l => l.First(r2 => r2.fieldName == "StudentId").value).Select(r => r.First()).ToList();
```

Comment: if you want the origional object rather than a new version

Comment: is an interesting problem which exposes the problems with Distinct(). instead you have to use the GroupBy(anon type).Select(first)

Answer (score 1):

First we group the elements of the `combinedList`:

```
var grouped = from x in combinedList
              group x by x.Where(y => y.fieldName == "StudentId").Select(y => y.value).FirstOrDefault();
```

We group them by the first `StudentId` we find (`x.Where(y => y.fieldName == "StudentId").Select(y => y.value).FirstOrDefault()`).

```
var res = (from x in grouped
           // We do a ToArray here because we will reuse the y
           // collection twice. In this way it isn't recalculated
           // every time. It isn't really necessary
           let y = x.SelectMany(z => z).ToArray()
           select y.Where(z => z.fieldName == "StudentId").Take(1).Concat(y.Where(z => z.fieldName != "StudentId")).ToArray())
          .ToArray();
```

Then through the `SelectMany` we flatten it.

In each group we put first an element of type `StudentId`, then all the other elements that aren't `StudentId`