# Group by multiple fields C# with object List

Tags: c#, linq, data-structures, lambda

I have the following data structure:

```
List<List<RecordItem>> combinedList = new List<List<RecordItem>>()
{
    new List<RecordItem>()
    {
        new RecordItem() { fieldName = "StudentId", value = "S1" },
        new RecordItem() { fieldName = "Maths", value = "90" },
        new RecordItem() { fieldName = "Term", value = "1" },
    },
    new List<RecordItem>()
    {
        new RecordItem() { fieldName = "StudentId", value = "S1" },
        new RecordItem() { fieldName = "Science", value = "70" },
        new RecordItem() { fieldName = "Term", value = "1" },
    }
};
```

I need to group it using StudentId and Term, I was able to group by one field -> studentId (Credits: Enigmativity) but unbale to group by multiple fields (studentId and term). 
The first issue is how to use LINQ to take another field (term)? and secondly, how to complete this code for the grouping.

```
List<List<RecordItem>> groupedList =
(
    from records in combinedList
    from student in records.Take(1) 
    from term   in records.Take(?) // how do I get the term which is the 4th element???
    let StudentId = student.value
    let Term = term.value
    let Subjects = records.Skip(1)
    group Subjects by new
    {
       StudentId,Term   
    into gss
    select new []
    {
        new RecordItem() { fieldName = "StudentId", value = gss.Key.StudentId },
        new RecordItem() { fieldName = "Term", value = gss.Key.Term },
    }.Concat(gss.SelectMany(x => x)).ToList()
).ToList();
```

Comment: @HimBromBeere: It's `Enumerable.ElementAt` and you get the 4th with `ElementAt(3)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't really understand what is going on here and what you are selecting, but this is syntactically correct code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<List<RecordItem>> combinedList = new List<List<RecordItem>>()
            {
                new List<RecordItem>()
                {
                    new RecordItem() { fieldName = "StudentId", value = "S1" },
                    new RecordItem() { fieldName = "Maths", value = "90" },
                    new RecordItem() { fieldName = "Term", value = "1" },
                },
                new List<RecordItem>()
                {
                    new RecordItem() { fieldName = "StudentId", value = "S1" },
                    new RecordItem() { fieldName = "Science", value = "70" },
                    new RecordItem() { fieldName = "Term", value = "1" },
                }
            };

            List<List<RecordItem>> groupedList =
            (
                from records in combinedList
                from student in records.Take(1)
                let StudentId = student.value
                let Term = records.ToArray().ElementAt(3).value
                let Subjects = records.Skip(1)
                group Subjects by new
                {
                    StudentId,
                    Term
                }
                    into gss
                    select new[]
                {
                    new RecordItem() { fieldName = "StudentId", value = gss.Key.StudentId },
                    new RecordItem() { fieldName = "Term", value = gss.Key.Term },
                }.Concat(gss.SelectMany(x => x)).ToList()
            ).ToList();
        }
```

Comment: You know that this code doesn't run - even after adding in the `RecordItem` class definition. It gives an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

Comment: @Enigmativity, I know. It's because of `records.ToArray().ElementAt(3)`. I didn't change this to 2, because OP wanted 4th element. I guess he knows about this.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you need:

```
List<List<RecordItem>> groupedList =
(
    from records in combinedList
    from student in records.Take(1)
    let StudentId = student.value
    from term in records.Skip(2).Take(1)
    let Term = term.value
    let Subjects = records.Skip(1).Take(1)
    group Subjects by new { StudentId, Term } into gss
    select new []
    {
        new RecordItem() { fieldName = "StudentId", value = gss.Key.StudentId },
        new RecordItem() { fieldName = "Term", value = gss.Key.Term },
    }.Concat(gss.SelectMany(x => x)).ToList()
).ToList();
```

Although, this data structure is getting worse by the second.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should try to use a better data structure than what you have. To put it bluntly, working with a List> is lame, and having to rely on the order of the items pretty much sucks. Do something about it: put your data in a `Dictionary<string,string>`, or even better, in your own custom class. Something like

```
public class MyData
{
    public string StudentId {get; set;}
    public string Maths {get; set;}
    public string Science {get; set;}
    public string Term {get; set;}
}
```

I'm not sure that's really the structure of data you want, and I'm almost certain some of these fields should be something else that `string`, but you get the idea.

Once you have your data well structured according to what you are willing to achieve, everything will get easier.

Now, if you have your previous data structure and want to project it to the nicer one you just created, it's not hard.

To project into a list of dictionaries:

```
var dictionaries = groupedList.Select(l => 
    l.ToDictionary(
        item => item.fieldName ,
        item => item.value)
    ).ToList();
```

Now you can project again to a better data structure:

```
var myTypedList = dictionaries.Select(d => new MyData
    {
        StudentId = d["StudentId"],
        Maths = d.ContainsKey("Maths") ? d["Maths"] : null,
        Science = d.ContainsKey("Science") ? d["Science"] : null,
        Term = d["Term"]
    }).ToList();
```

Now, you can do the grouping you want easily:

```
var myResults = myTypedList.GroupBy(val => new {val.StudentId, val.Term})
    .Select(group => new {
        StudentId = group.Key.StudentId,
        Term = group.Key.Term,
        Maths = group.First(v => v.Maths != null).Maths,
        Science = group.First(v => v.Science != null).Science
}).ToList();
```

Remember that most of your work will be done when you have figured the right data structure for your specific problem. Try to be as specific as possible, it will make your code both easier to write and easier to read. Trying to be "smart" only working with imbricated lists of senseless classes will get you nowhere. The work you do on the modelling is the most important.